# Why does SimpleCov trigger when rake db:schema:load is executed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rake-task, simplecov

If I have a `.simplecov` file, then when I run `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:schema:load`, I get a coverage report.

If I move the code from `.simplecov` to my `test_helper.rb` file (I use MiniTest), this does not happen.

I expect that this should never happen - loading the schema in the test environment is not a coverage test.

The reason this is annoying is that it causes my schema to load on CircleCI, generates a coverage below my threshold, and then fails the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably posted this question before a recent change to the `simplecov` readme... the change I needed to avoid this problem was to update my Gemfile to turn off auto-requiring of the simplecov gem:

`gem 'simplecov', require: false`

I then explicitly added Simplecov to my `test/test_helper.rb` as recommended in the README and that fixed this problem.